# ng-repeat repeats but data fields are not evalueated

Tags: angularjs

I have a bootstrap menu that is rendered using angular

Here is the controller that I use

```
function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.MenuEntries = {}
        $http.get('/menu/')
        .success(
            function (response)
            {
                $scope.MenuEntries = response.data;
                console.log($scope.MenuEntries);
            })
        .error();
    }
```

And this is my template

```
  <ul class=nav>
      <li ng-repeat='entry in MenuEntries'>
         <li>
            <a href='{{entry.link}}'>{{entry.display_name}}<b class=caret></b></a>
            <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
               <li ng-repeat='child in entry.children'>
                  <a href='{{child.link}}'>{{child.display_name}}</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

This is my response,

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "children": [], 
        "display_name": "Home", 
        "link": "/#/", 
    }, 
    {
        "children": [], 
        "display_name": "Logout", 
        "link": "/logout/", 
    }, 
    {
        "children": [
                "display_name": "View Attendance", 
                "link": "/#/attendance/view", 
            }, 
            {
                "display_name": "Attendance Summary", 
                "link": "/#/attendance/summary", 
            }
        ], 
        "display_name": "Attendance", 
        "link": "#", 
    }
]
}
```

This gets logged in the console as a perfect JS array with perfect JS objects

And finally, this is my HTML generated

```
    <ul class="nav">
        <!-- ngRepeat: entry in MenuEntries -->
          <li ng-repeat="entry in MenuEntries" class="ng-scope"></li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: entry in MenuEntries -->
          <li ng-repeat="entry in MenuEntries" class="ng-scope"></li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: entry in MenuEntries -->
          <li ng-repeat="entry in MenuEntries" class="ng-scope"></li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: entry in MenuEntries -->
        <li>
          <a href=""><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <!-- ngRepeat: child in entry.children -->
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Why isn't my data populated in the template?

Comment: Stupid question but are you initializing the app and the controller in the HTML?

Comment: no, there is no js in my html file, if that is what you are asking

Comment: I mean, do you have ng-app and ng-controller attributes in your HTML? Those are required.

Comment: yes they do :) you can see the angular code working in the last snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ng-repeat`, you shouldn't repeat the element the directive is applied to within its template. In your case, that means you just have to remove the `<li>` that immediately follows `<li ng-repeat>`:

```
<li ng-repeat='entry in MenuEntries'>
  <a href='{{entry.link}}'>{{entry.display_name}}<b class=caret></b></a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
    <li ng-repeat='child in entry.children'>
      <a href='{{child.link}}'>{{child.display_name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

BTW, you might consider removing the child-related `<ul>` completely if `entry.children` are empty. For example:

```
<!-- the same code as above -->
<ul ng-if="entry.children.length" class='dropdown-menu'>
  <li ng-repeat='child in entry.children'>
    <a href='{{child.link}}'>{{child.display_name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$scope.$apply();` after the MenuEntries is updated.
The new values have to be applied on the Page.